# How to add card to Apple Pay using PKAddPaymentPassViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, passkit

I did enough research to add credit/debit cards listed in my app to add to Apple Pay. I understood from Apple Developer Forums Using private APIs is forbidden by apple for this purpose.

As i contacted them, i got awareness of PKAddPaymentPassViewController.
This class contain some set of methods and delegates.

Actually i want to know how to use this, when to use this Controller, how to set up this to get it done.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods

Answer (score 0):

> The following answer is got from [quora.](https://www.quora.com/Does-Passbook-support-a-way-for-allowing-users-to-add-a-credit-card-to-Apple-Pay-from-their-credit-card-or-mobile-banking-app)

Apple do supports this feature and exposes an API where an Issuer or Bank can push the token directly from their mobile banking app. Now the onus is on Issuer or bank to support this feature.

Disclaimer: This is only available to Issuer of credit card and not third party apps.

Comment: Can we add card details without issuer using Pass Kit and PKAddPaymentPassViewController. We will connect with issuer in future.

Comment: @Sudhi9135 If you’re third party,it’s no. If not,contact Apple,please.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any other way like adding credit to Wallet using Pass kit.

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214137/569507

If you have further questions let me know.

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: No, you absolutely did not answer this question anywhere :)