# How to add a credit/debit card into apple wallet from the ios App

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet

I would be really helpful if anyone provides a solution to know, **how do we add the credit/debit card details to Wallet from our App**. I have the credit/debit card details for the user and when user tap on Apple Pay option in my App, the Add Card screen in Apple Wallet need to be opened with card data pre-populated. How do we achieve the same.  
 Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot add credit cards from an app.

Comment: Can we add debit card to wallet?

Comment: You can't add anything to the top half of the wallet, unless you are the card issuer (and have an agreement with Apple).  For the bottom half, then there is an open API to create tickets, boarding passes, coupons, loyalty cards, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to know, instead of user adding their debit/credit card details explicitly to Wallet(Passbook) App, Can our app do the task by collection card details from user and take the user to Add Card screen in Wallet?

Comment: The best you can do is to offer a screen advising the user what to do.  Why do you even need the credit card details?  One of the fundamental principles of Apple Pay is not needing to share the underlying credit card details with the merchant.  I imagine that even if you succeed in what you are tying to do, the probability of getting the app approved by Apple would be low.

Comment: basically it's a banking application, where we have the customer card details with the app, we are giving one more option to add existing the card to wallet. So that it will be helpful for them.

Comment: In that case - if you are the card issuer, I would talk directly with your Apple Pay representative.  A lot of the "top half" of the wallet documentation is only available under NDA, but they would be best placed to get you with the resources and information required.

Comment: @PrasanthRaj did you achieve your requirement.

Comment: @PrasanthRaj Prasanth, Could you please tell me what should be the implementation for addPaymentPassViewController:generateRequestWithCertificateChain:nonce:nonceSignature:completionHandler:

Comment: @PassKit is exist official documented answers on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The good news is that this *can* be done. What you are looking for is **In-App Provisioning of Payment Cards**. This is done using the `PKAddPaymentPassViewController`, which requires the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement key for your app. The bad news is that not anyone can submit apps with this entitlement as it requires special permission from Apple, which I believe is reserved for card issuers like banks and similar. If you believe that you qualify you need to contact Apple directly at `apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com`.

Comment: I added this com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entilement in Entilement file gettign code signing error...

Comment: Is exist official documented answers on this?

Comment: @Hrvoje https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

[Apple only want to communicate with bank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5R0g.png)@pajevic

Abreast of the times email address is: *apple-pay-provisioning@apple.com*

on the https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/     we can find  in Lower right corner [image: snapshot]

Comment: when replying to other answers you should post as a comment to the answer rather than creating another answer