# What behaviour is pereferable for Apple Pay button if no cards in the wallet?

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet, design-guidelines

I was looked through the apple guidelines but did not found anything about this question.

**Additional info:**

I have added Apple Pay button to app and hide it if there are no capabilities (e.g., cards) to pay with. But customer does not like it and wants *some other* approach. I think we may open wallet like asking user to add a card, but I am not sure what Apple guidelines think about it.

Is there any explicit recommendation about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is Apple's [guidelines  on implementing Apple Pay.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH3-SW2)

Here is the relevant section:
Using [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller) methods

> If `canMakePayments` returns `NO`, the device does not support Apple Pay. Do not display the Apple Pay button. Instead, fall back to another method of payment.
>
> If `canMakePayments` returns `YES` but `canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks`: returns `NO`, the device supports Apple Pay, but the user has not added a card for any of the requested networks. You can, optionally, display a payment setup button, prompting the user to set up his or her card. As soon as the user taps this button, initiate the process of setting up a new card (for example, by calling the openPaymentSetup method).
>
> To create an Apple Pay–branded button for initiating payment request on iOS 8.3 or later, use the [PKPaymentButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentbutton) class.

From the PKPaymentButton docs:

> Provides a button that is used either to trigger payments through
>   Apple Pay or to prompt the user to set up a card.

You can initialize it with a type `setUp`.

When the user taps this button, call [openPaymentSetup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617100-openpaymentsetup).

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var applePayButton: PKPaymentButton?
    if !PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments() {
      // Apple Pay not supported
      return
    }
    if !PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: [.masterCard]) {
      // Apple Pay supported and payment not setup
      applePayButton = PKPaymentButton.init(paymentButtonType: .setUp, paymentButtonStyle: .black)
      applePayButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.setupPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else {
      // Apple Pay supported and payment setup
      applePayButton = PKPaymentButton.init(paymentButtonType: .buy, paymentButtonStyle: .black)
      applePayButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.payPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    applePayButton?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(applePayButton!)
    applePayButton?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    applePayButton?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    applePayButton?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    applePayButton?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

  }

  @objc func payPressed(_ sender: PKPaymentButton){
    // Start payment
  }

  @objc func setupPressed(_ sender: PKPaymentButton){
    let passLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
    passLibrary.openPaymentSetup()
  }

}
```