# Error while trying to add payment card to Apple Wallet

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ionic3

Well, I am developing a Cordova plugin to enable users from adding credit/debit cards to thier wallet.

I am using `PKAddPaymentPassViewController`, **not** `PKAddPassViewController`.

I have created the plugin itself successfully, with one method `startAddPaymentPass` (for now). It takes the following parameters:

```
{
  cardholderName: 'Hamada',
  primaryAccountNumberSuffix: '1234567',
  localizedDescription: 'Green Travel',
  primaryAccountIdentifier: '987654321',
  paymentNetwork: 'Visa'
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
missing entitlement: com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning
ERROR: ERROR >>  MISSING_ENTITLEME NTS
```

Could anyone help? Or if anyone interested can contribute building the whole plugin with me.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a special entitlement issued by Apple.

> Your app must include this entitlement before you can use this class.
>   For more information on requesting this entitlement, see the Card
>   Issuers section at developer.apple.com/apple-pay/.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708918/how-to-add-a-credit-debit-card-into-apple-wallet-from-the-ios-app/46214137#46214137):

> `PKAddPaymentPassViewController` requires the
>   `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement key for your
>   app. The bad news is that not anyone can submit apps with this
>   entitlement as it requires special permission from Apple, which I
>   believe is reserved for card issuers like banks and similar. If you
>   believe that you qualify you need to contact Apple directly at
>   `apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com`

Comment: Yes, I have passed all steps and verified from bank side. The problem was mainly because `.entitlements` file was missing. Then, I noticed that in XCode 9 that there is no `.entitlements` file anymore and instead I need to edit `.plist` files located in the project folder itself
`Entitlements-Debug.plist` and `Entitlements-Release.plist`

Comment: What should be implementation for PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: In your experience how long does it take to get permission or a response from Apple after you contact them at the apple-pay-inquiries email address?

Comment: hey, I've moved to work on different work so I'm not sure about how long it takes now.