# How to add Apple Wallet Passes with custom name and QR code in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I add an Apple Wallet pass with a custom username and contents of a QR code? If possible can they be downloaded from a server?

I have tried altering existing passes but there is no capability to do that in Xamarin.

Comment: you could look at [PassKit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/passkit?tabs=windows),maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1):

So the beauty of using Xamarin is that you have access to all the native iOS APIs that are available to Swift developers, so you can do everything in C# that you can with Swift without the need for custom binding.

So anything that you can do using Swift on XCode, you can do that in an identical way using C#. So in order to implement the Apple Wallet passes, you have to go through the same procedures. The procedure is slightly long since this is for Card Issuers only and you need a special entitlement issued by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary):

> Your app must include this entitlement before you can use this class.
>   For more information on requesting this entitlement, see the Card
>   Issuers section at developer.apple.com/apple-pay/.

Also, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214137/11104068):

> `PKAddPaymentPassViewController` requires the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement
>   key for your app. The bad news is that not anyone can submit apps with
>   this entitlement as it requires special permission from Apple, which I
>   believe is reserved for card issuers like banks and similar. If you
>   believe that you qualify you need to contact Apple directly at
>   `apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com`

Once you get that done, you need to implement the delegate methods, and initialize it with a configuration as you can see in the code/picture below [(Converted from Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196768/11104068):

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using PassKit;
using UIKit;

namespace BlankNativeApp.iOS
{
    public class PKViewController : UIViewController, IPKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate
    {
        public void DidFinishAddingPaymentPass(PKAddPaymentPassViewController controller, PKPaymentPass pass, NSError error)
        {
            // Perform Post Addition Functionality
        }

        public void GenerateRequestWithCertificateChain(PKAddPaymentPassViewController controller, NSData[] certificates, NSData nonce, NSData nonceSignature, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity1V173))] Action<PKAddPaymentPassRequest> handler)
        {
            // Do work that needs to be done with certifications
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            if (!PKAddPaymentPassViewController.CanAddPaymentPass)
            {
                // use other payment method / alert user
            }
            var config = new PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration(PKEncryptionScheme.Ecc_V2);
            var addPaymentPassVC = new PKAddPaymentPassViewController(config, this);
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            Title = "My Custom View Controller";

            var btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System);
            btn.Frame = new CGRect(20, 200, 280, 44);
            btn.SetTitle("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);
            btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                //this.ShowViewController(addPaymentPassVC, (Foundation.NSObject)sender); This line will also work
                this.PresentViewControllerAsync(addPaymentPassVC, true);
            };
            View.AddSubview(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Implementation example for Passkit]